# pointer/struct free() - Heap Corruption

Tags: c, heap-corruption

I have a small, but annoying, problem here.

So here are my structures.

```
typedef struct tElem {
    struct tElem *ptr;
    int data;
} *tElemPtr;


typedef struct {
    tElemPtr Act;
    tElemPtr First;
} tList;
```

And here is the allocation. This is where the **heap corruption** occurs.

```
tElemPtr newElemPtr = (tElemPtr)malloc(sizeof(tElemPtr));
.
.
.
free(newElemPtr);
```

But it doesn't occur, when I use size of the actual structure.

```
tElemPtr newElemPtr = (tElemPtr)malloc(sizeof(struct tElem));
.
.
.
free(newElemPtr);
```

Could somebody please explain to me, what am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: `sizeof(tElemPtr)` is the size of a _pointer_ to `struct tElem` and _not_ the size of the struct itself [because `tElemPtr` is a typedef for: `struct tElem *`]. You need to allocate enough space to contain the `struct` and _not_ just a pointer to it, hence, using `sizeof(struct tElem)` is what works (i.e. it's [probably] 16 bytes vs 4/8 bytes for the pointer).

Comment: @dxiv But, don't cast `malloc` ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: @CraigEstey Right, of course. That should have been just `tElemPtr newElemPtr = malloc(sizeof(*newElemPtr));`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are mallocing a pointer not a new struct

`sizeof(tElemPtr)` is going to return the size of a pointer not the size of the struct.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thank you very much. EDIT: If I may ask, is there any way of allocating without using the "struct tElem"?